# Differentiate between S3 object creation events vs object metadata updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-redshift

I am inserting S3 events to a Redshift table from which I intend to find out the total number of files as well as the total size of a bucket. I am using Lambda functions to capture PUT, POST and DELETE events and write these to kinesis firehose from where these are push directly to a Redshift table. The problem is that in my lambda function, I have no way to know if an event is a create event for an s3 object or an update event (such as when you change redundancy settings or server side encryption). Now I have a bunch of events in a table against the same file, making it difficult to calculate the actual size of the bucket. What would you recommend I do? Thanks.

Here is what my redshift table looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as each row contains a timestamp and the size of the file at that time, and it looks like it does from your screenshot, you should be able to do this with the `LAST_VALUE` or `FIRST_VALUE` window functions.

Something like this

```
WITH latest_sizes AS (
  SELECT
    bucketname,
    keyname,
    LAST_VALUE(filesize) OVER (
      PARTITION BY bucketname, keyname
      ORDER BY lastupdated
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    ) AS filesize
  FROM s3_events
)
SELECT
  bucketname,
  keyname,
  MAX(filesize) AS filesize
FROM latest_sizes
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

should give you the last reported size per bucket and key, if you want the total size per bucket you can replace the last part with

```
SELECT
  bucketname,
  MAX(filesize) AS total_size
FROM latest_sizes
GROUP BY 1
```

The query works like this: `latest_sizes` will result in a relation with a row for every row in the `s3_events` table (I'm making up a name of the table, substitute it for yours), but instead of each update's `filesize` the `filesize` column will have the value from the latest update. This may sound a bit weird, but try this part of the query out in isolation and play around with the parameters and you might see what I mean.

The magic is in the `LAST_VALUE` window function. Window functions work on the current row and a subset of all other rows. In this case I've defined the window to be all other rows with the same `bucketname` and `keyname`, ordered by `lastupdated`. This means that the latest update for each object will be in the last row of the window, and `LAST_VALUE` picks that for me. I could have used `FIRST_VALUE` to get the first update (or ordered `DESC`).

It would have been nice to be able to group by `bucketname` and `keyname` in the same query as the window function, but I can't figure out how to get Redshift to do that. Instead I've added a second part that does the grouping. I use `MAX` to get the size, but `MIN` would have worked just as well, I actually only need the value from some row, because they will all have the same value. Come to think of it `SELECT DISTINCT bucketname, keyname, filesize FROM latest_sizes` should work too.

Comment: Thanks .. this would work!  My original question was simpler, as I wanted to find out the number of files. I figured this part out myself however your answer addresses what I would have run into next i-e the size of bucket in bytes if the file size has been updated.  Thanks for the LAST_VALUE hint.

Comment: Did you use a window function to solve the number of files too? I think it should be possible to solve with `LAST_VALUE` too by using it on the `operation` column and then in the second step filtering out the lines where the `operation = DELETE`.

Comment: I didnt use the window function for number of files. I took a count of the distinct files having operation as 'INSERT' subtracted by count of distinct files having operation as 'DELETE'. That would work since there is no such thing as a rename of a file in S3 right ?

Comment: That sounds like it would work for to get the totals for a bucket.